# What's wrong with this simple file.managed saltstack configuration?

Tags: file, salt-stack

From a fresh salt stack installation on server and client, the goal is to serve a file with a number  inside:

SERVER
$vim /etc/salt/master

```
...
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
...
```

$echo 1 > /srv/salt/tmp/salt.config.version
$cat /srv/salt/top.sls

```
base:
  '*':
    - tmpversion
```

$cat /srv/salt/tmpversion/init.sls

```
/tmp/salt.config.version:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://tmp/salt.config.version
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
```

CLIENT (minion)
$vim /etc/salt/minion

```
...
master: <masterhostnamehere>
...
```

I'm using **salt '*' state.sls tmpversion** to apply the configuration. I don't know how to get the changes applied automatically..

Comment: Can you provide the exact cli command you're using to apply this state and the output you're getting?

Comment: I'm using **salt '*' state.sls tmpversion**. It's working but does not persist.

Comment: What duo you mean by, "It's working, but does not persist"?

Comment: When I run **salt '*' state.sls tmpversion** it works as expected creating the tmp file. But if I remove the tmp file it does not automatically reapply the state. I have to manually run the command again. Should I use crontab to ensure the command gets executed once in a while?

Comment: yes, you should use cron or some other scheduler to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt doesn't do anything until you tell it to. So that means that you have to run the salt command on the cli when you want a state to be applied, or you can use Salt's internal scheduler or your system's cron to run the job regularly.

Comment: This is why I love salt. I control when my changes are made, not random cron jobs.